# Замена strcpy и ошибки C4996, E0304, C2660

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Как можно заменить strcpy не теряя работоспособности?

```
for (i = 0; i < kol; i++)
    if ((strcmp(Regname.Name, mas[i].Name) == 0) && (strcmp(Regname.Password, mas[i].Password) == 0)) {
        strcpy(role, mas[i].role);
        delete[]mas;
        return Regname.Name;
    }
```

Появился данный вопрос, т.к. постоянно вылазит ошибка о небезопасной функции или переменной.

Ошибка C4996.
Чтобы её решить define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS не вариант.

Хотелось бы услышать ответ для современного уровня, если strcpy "устарел".

Замена на strcpy_s вызывает другие ошибки:

- отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция функция "strcpy_s", соответствующие списку аргументов.
- strcpy_s: функция не принимает 2 аргументов

Если писать 3 аргумента, как и положено, выводит ошибку: [image: клик]

Comment: `Хотелось бы услышать ответ для современного уровня` — может использовать [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: Если отчего-то необходимо работать именно с массивами С-style, то передавайте аргументы, как того требует `strcpy_s`.

Comment: @VTT да, я знаю что требуется 3 параметра. После компиляции и запуска программы выводит это: https://imgur.com/ptS5xg1

Comment: Используй `strncpy()`

Comment: @Fat-Zer также вызывает C4996.

Comment: @Fat-Zer: `strncpy` здесь вообще ни к чему.

Comment: Ну и? Ваша ошибка никакого отношения ни к `strcpy`, ни к  `strcpy_s` не имеет. При чем здесь она?

Comment: `strcpy_s` в С++ коде перегружена версией, требующей только два параметра, когда используется с *массивом*.

Comment: @AnT, думал M$ только strcpy() объявило нежелательной (по понятным причинам), однако похоже кто-то увидел эфемерные выгоды и для strncpy()...

Comment: "*Если писать 3 аргумента, как и положено, выводит ошибку*" - вообще-то указанная ошибка относится к работе с файлами, а не со строками!

Comment: И как тогда исправить такое? Совсем запутался.